# Is heap allocated object guaranteed to be alive when it is returned from a function with std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, heap-memory, shared-ptr

I am learning C++. I just learned `std::shared_ptr` can be used for managing heap-allocated object as in reference-counting manner.

Currently my compiler (Xcode/Clang/C++11) shows exact behavior what I wanted.
Prints this result,

```
Step0
Step1
CREATED!
Step2
Step3
Step5
DESTROYED!
Step6
```

with this code.

```
class   Obj1
{
    public:
        Obj1() { printf("CREATED!\n"); }
        ~Obj1() { printf("DESTROYED!\n"); }
};

std::shared_ptr<Obj1> func1 ()
{
    printf("Step0\n");
    {
        printf("Step1\n");
        std::shared_ptr<Obj1>   o1(new Obj1());
        printf("Step2\n");
        std::shared_ptr<Obj1>   o2  =   o1;
        printf("Step3\n");
        return  o2;
    }
    printf("Step4\n");
}



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Obj1>   o3  =   func1();
        printf("Step5\n");
    }
    printf("Step6\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But as far as I know, this can be happen by C++'s copy constructor optimization when the `std::shared_ptr` is assigned to new variable. (I am not sure the name...) If it is, the `Obj1` instance maybe not guaranteed to be alive when it is being returned from the function, because actually the `shared_ptr` is destroyed and re-creared at caller semantically.

Of course all these are newbie's assumption. Please let me know what actually expected on object lifetime in this case.

PS. This is derived from my previous question: 
[Good practice or convention for cleanup heap allocated object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126006/good-practice-or-convention-for-cleanup-heap-allocated-object)

Comment: *"...this can be happen by C++'s copy constructor optimization when the std::shared_ptr is assigned to new variable."* - You mean when `o2` in `func1()` is copied to `o3` in `main()`? *"(I am not sure the name...)"* - Do you also mean **R** eturn-**V** alue **O** ptimization?

Comment: @MarkGarcia Currently I think `o3` is newly created by copying `o2`. And I am not sure the reference count can be dropped to `0` at function borderline. That's the question...

Comment: @MarkGarcia And I think that's RVO. I couldn't figure out the name. Thanks.

Comment: The language would be unusable if it worked the way you fear. If the RVO doesn't happen then the object inside the function gets destroyed _after_ another copy has been made, so the `Obj1` gets kept alive by the new copy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either `o2`'s lifetime is extended or a copy of it is made before it's destroyed. Either way, at least one `shared_ptr` always exists, so the code is safe.

Comment: Can I sure this is guaranteed by C++ semantics, not by a side-effect of optimization?

Comment: @Eonil The standard is formed by brilliant people (though they like undefined behaviors too much). They have scrutinized (almost) every possible usage scenarios for these things. Rest assured. You are in safe hands.

Comment: @Eonil: It is guaranteed that one of those two things will happen and both of them are safe.

Answer (score 4):

You misunderstand how that optimization works. Lets say we have small example:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> func()
{
    std::shared_ptr o2;
    o2.reset( new Foo  );
    return o2;
}
std::shared_ptr<Foo> o1 = func();
```

What compiler can do by optimization would look like this (not exactly but will help to understand the idea):

```
void func( std::shared_ptr<Foo> &o2 )
{
    o2.reset( new Foo  );
}
std::shared_ptr<Foo> o1;
func( o1 );
```

So from your point of view almost nothing changed, only copy of object (smart pointer) is eliminated. It would not affect lifetime of Foo.