# Getting roots for Mark Sweep Garbage Collector C++

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, garbage

My goal is to create simple mark-sweep garbage collector in C++ language. First step in mark phase is to get all roots(thread stacks, global variables ...). So, how can i get or find that roots in my c++ code?

Comment: You will probably need to write a compiler that collects this information.

Comment: Look at the Boehm conservative collector for one possible approach: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector

Comment: One possible thing that you could do is to call a function to register each root object, and let your collector keep a list. Not very convenient, but easy to implement (compared to writing a new compiler), and could still be useful for some cases. Or look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147130/why-doesnt-c-have-a-garbage-collector?rq=1

Comment: Yes, i saw Boehm collector. I'll give it a try again... Is it possible(i mean easier to implement) collector for C++, but written in C?
Edit: Not sure i'm gonna write a new compiler. I'm looking for easiest solution for this part of job, if there is one.

Comment: a precise collector needs to know the object and stack frame layout. a conservative one can just scan memory regions (stacks, heap) for potential pointers into those regions.

Comment: https://github.com/hsutter/gcpp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a talk that Herb Sutter gave at [CPPCon 2016](https://cppcon.org/) that explains exactly how to correctly make a mark-n-sweep garbage collector in C++: [Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE)