# Pointers in a linked list example

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I was implementing a linked list until I came across

```
void StringLinkedList::removeFront(){ 

StringNode *old = head;
head = old -> next;
delete old;

}
```

I was wondering why not just do head = head->next (instead of head = old->next), how does this create a memory leak when there is nothing pointing to the previous address (since head the head node is now pointing to the next node).

Thank you so much.

Comment: If you still have these 3 lines but in the second line change old to head - the code will be the same and no memory leak will be introduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ does not have automated garbage collection like some other languages that release storage once it is no longer referenced. There are a number of reasons for this, and a discussion on the topic can be found in [Why doesn't C++ have a garbage collector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147130/why-doesnt-c-have-a-garbage-collector).

This means that which is `new`ed must be `delete`d or you have a leak.

Say you have

[image]

If you do not `delete` the original value of `head` before overwriting `head`,

[image]

the address of Node 1 is no longer known, making it next to impossible to track down the allocation in order to `delete` it. This forces a leak.

But if you `delete head` before re-pointing it,

[image]

you can't `head->next` to find the next node, and you lose and leak the whole list.

However, if you make a temporary copy of the address of `head`,

[image]

`old` in this case, you can safely re-point `head`

[image]

and still have the address of the allocation you need to `delete` stored in `old`.

Comment: the code I was looking at did not create head with 'new' though is this an error?

Comment: @coder666 You aren't really deleting `head`. You are deleting what `head` points at. `head` could point at any `Node`, and if `head` points at a `Node` created by `new`, someone must `delete` it sooner or later. Keyword: "Ownership semantics". In this case, the linked list is the owner of the `Node` and `head` is where the linked list stores  the reference to the `Node`. As for `head` itself, it is an automatic variable that will be taken care of for you when it goes out of scope.

Comment: I get it ! Thank you !