# Solving memory leak in mql5

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

I am using this code for getting information from a website that I **scrape** for news and getting these two error messages on the expert log

1. 806912 bytes of leaked memory
2. 1 leaked strings left

When I ran get the last error message, I get ERR_INVALID_ARRAY

here is the function that I suspect is causing the error, I am suspecting that it has something to do with these two arrays post[], result[] though I am not sure. Any form of help will be appreciated

```
string ReadCBOE()
   {
      string cookie=NULL,headers;
      char post[], result[];     
      string TXT="";
      int res;
      string str;
      
      static string str2 = "";
   
      string google_url="http://ec.forexprostools.com/?columns=exc_currency,exc_importance&importance=1,2,3&calType=week&timeZone=15&lang=1";
      ResetLastError();
      int timeout=5000; 
      res=WebRequest("GET",google_url,cookie,NULL,timeout,post,0,result,headers);
      if(res==-1)
      {
         Print("WebRequest error, err.code  =",GetLastError());
         MessageBox("You must add the address 'http://ec.forexprostools.com/' in the list of allowed URL tab 'Advisors' "," Error ",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
      }
      else
      {
         int filehandle=FileOpen("news-log.html",FILE_WRITE|FILE_BIN|FILE_ANSI);
         if(filehandle!=INVALID_HANDLE)
         {
            FileWriteArray(filehandle,result,0,ArraySize(result));
            FileClose(filehandle);
            //------+
            int file_handle=FileOpen("news-log.html",FILE_READ|FILE_BIN|FILE_ANSI);
            if(file_handle!=INVALID_HANDLE)
            {
               do
               {
                  ResetLastError();
                  string Largestr=FileReadString(file_handle,4000);
                  if(GetLastError()!=0) break;
                  StringConcatenate(str,str,Largestr);
               }
               while(GetLastError()==0 && !FileIsEnding(file_handle));
               FileClose(file_handle);
            }
            else PrintFormat("Failed to open %s file, Error code = %d","news-log.html",GetLastError());
         }
      }
   return(str);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late to help the OP, but...

`StringConcatenate` was repeatedly reported with this kind of leak-memory problems, especially in loops. Also, it's slower than [`StringAdd`](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/strings/stringadd), which I'd use in situations like this.

That said, I didn't understand the reason to write to a log file and immediately read from it when the data is already in a variable. It could be much easier/faster using [`CharArrayToString`](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/convert/chararraytostring) right before return it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that the reason why you are seeing leaked memory is because you are not handling your error(s) properly. From what I understand, there is no garbage collector in c++, which I believe MQL is a subset of [See here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147130/why-doesnt-c-have-a-garbage-collector).

As such, when an exception is being thrown, you still have allocated memory that is not released (i.e. your string). Try clearing the string (set to `null`) when an error is thrown. Think that may remove the error leak issue.