What are the reasons why PHP does not provide a builtin deepcopy function like Python?
Yes, you can implement __clone and manually call clone for variables that reference objects, but couldn't PHP do this automatically using e.g. the is_object, is_array functions and other similar functions needed to check if we need to make a deep copy or not?
I'm not asking for opinions. I'm asking for good technical (maybe official) reasons why this function does not seem to exist. If this has been proposed, can you provide the link?
I suppose this could be related to circular references, which can cause problems, but such a builtin could e.g. raise an error if it detects a circular reference or do something else that could make sense, which maybe can be controlled by some parameter.
Python provides such as function deepcopy, but I am also not super familiar with its implementation.
Please, do not state

php's clone does a shallow copy by default and that I can override __clone to perform a deep copy
I can use serialise and unserialise to perform a deep copy and this might not be a good idea for performance reasons
I can use a third party library to perform the deep copy

I'm only interested in the reasons why the people in charge of PHP have not yet decided to add a builtin deepcopy function.

When most programming languages do not have built-in deep copy functionality, shouldn't you ask why Python has a deepcopy method?

@shingo java has one too, both python and java ones are based on serialize and unserialize. C# doesn't have an explicit deepcopy function but it has serialize and unserialize which are used for that purpose

Python deepcopy is basically serialize + unserialize. It uses pickle under the hood

Deep copyability is only truely provided by languages which have value semantics like c++ and swift and C# value types and rust, while php like java and python doesn't have value semantics, so both others wrap serialize + unserialize in a function and call it deepcopy. You would just be more likely to use a function named deepcopy than a function named serialize_and_unserialize

@AhmedAEK "java has one too" Really? Where?

@Olivier org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.clone(T), though i think the SerializationUtils in its package name gives away what it does

@AhmedAEK That's a third-party library.

at least for python case, python has "some" support to allow a type to be treated like a value type because you can override __copy__ and __deepcopy__  if you want faster deepcopying than what pickle does, but for java typically uses copy constructors to simulate this effect, but it is manual labor that you have to go through if you want something that deepcopies fast.

This topic would be much better suited for a discussion. There probably isn't a very good technical reason for not having a deep copy function. It's probably more a non-technical reason. It's also a bit like asking why there aren't blue apples, when there are blue grapes. Oh, there are blue apples?

Being rude to people will probably not help your quest for an answer. Well, it shouldn't. There are enough loud mouths controlling our lives as it is.

@KIKOSoftware Where am I being rude? Why should I care about your opinions and speculations? I specifically stated I don't want opinions and it's ironic that you closed this as opinion-based. It seems you're doing your job well. But well this is Stack Overflow.

Saying you don't care about what people have to say, who are trying to help you, can be perceived as rude. You must be aware that. Just because this is Stack Overflow doesn't change that. Anyway, why not post this as an discussion? It would allow people to more freely discuss this matter. That is, if you're open to that. Just realize that there are sometimes issues that don't have a purely technical answer. This looks like one of them. That doesn't mean it isn't an interesting issue.

If you only want answers from PHP contributors then ask them, not us

@AhmedAEK "Python deepcopy is basically serialize + unserialize" - Not for any of the main types.

I have to agree there are lots of things wrong with Stack Overflow. I have been annoyed many times by the way it functions. It comes over as a simple forum where you can ask free-form programming question, but in reality it is not. There are some quite strict guidelines about what you can ask. You must be aware of those, and shouldn't be surprised when they are enforced. Why else have these rules? What I did not do is turn this around on the community and call the people here toxic and degenerate. Many people do, I know. It's the easy way.

@KIKOSoftware So what part of the guidelines that my question falls into that make my question off-topic? My question is - what are the technical/programming limitations why a specific function is not implemented in PHP? How is my question different than say this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/147130/3924118, which received 300+ upvotes and has not been closed? You can try to find the excuses you want why you closed this question, but I don't see why this question is off-topic or opinion based, when I explicitly asked that I don't want opinions and I want to know the technical reasons.

Stack Overflow isn't operated by machines, there are humans making a human judgement. Inconsistency is bound to happen, and there is a lot of it on Stack Overflow. Anyway, I will keep following this question, since you don't seem to want to start a discussion, and if anybody indicates that an objective answer is known, I will aid in reopening this question. As for now, I doubt such an answer exists. A similar question could also be asked of every other functionality not build into PHP. Is that useful? Again, I don't think so.

Are you just curious, or would you also actually like to have it? In the latter case, you could request it as feature, and if they reject it, they might give you your answer.

Actually I think the question shouldn't have been closed because it's opinion-based, but rather because it's not "a specific programming problem" (see here for the definition of on-topic questions). And yes, you are right that many questions like "Why doesn't C++ have a garbage collector" are off-topic and could be closed. In practice, it seems that old off-topic questions are kept open and new ones are closed.

"Some PHP contributors are also here on Stack Overflow" I've been watching the PHP tag for a few years now, and I have never seen a PHP contributor make a comment or answer a question.

@Olivier Asking why something was (or was not) designed a certain way, or why a language/tool/whatever has a (or doesn't have) a feature, is considered "opinion-based" on Stack Overflow, because you're unlikely to receive an authoritative answer, but more likely to receive opinions, guesses and conjecture.

@MarkRotteveel That seems silly. Take for example this recent "why" question which I simply answered by quoting the documented rationale. I think in a few other cases I found the answer in GitHub issue discussions or so. And sometimes I've seen the actual developers answering. Just because most people would only speculate doesn't mean answering with facts is impossible.

@Olivier Yes, people that are really working on important problems might not spend much time on a toxic site like this. But yes there's, and I have the actual names and profiles, but I'll not share them. You can search for them if you really want.

Regarding the why questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=why. You can find some many examples of highly upvoted questions, which were not closed, that ask why questions. In my case, I'm actually asking what are the technical reasons or limitations why the deepcopy was not implemented. Was it because of circular references? Can you provide an example of why circular references make it difficult to implement a safe deepcopy in all cases? I don't know how many times I have to repeat myself, but it seems a lot of times until people get it.
