# Is there a garbage collecting class for C++

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, c++11

Is there a class that does garbage collection for C++. I was thinking something like:

```
class A : public GarbageCollected<A>
{
  void kill()
  {
     GarbageCollected<A>.set_cleanup_flag();
  }
  ...
private:
  GarbageCollectedPointer<B> b_pointer; // Somehow we follow 
  GarbageCollectedPointer<B> b_pointer2; // these pointers.
};

class B
{
  ...
};

class GarbageContainer
{
  ...
};

int main()
{
  GarbageContainer gc;
  gc.add(new A());
  ...
}
```

The idea being that `GarbageContainer` would do mark and sweep on the objects or some other garbage collection method. It would save having to do reference counting and using weak_ptrs and garbage collection could be used just for objects it is felt necessary.

Are there any libraries that implement something like this?

Comment: There is a comparison of many of the solutions available on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81062/garbage-collectors-for-c).

Comment: Before even going there, stop and think why you need it. Every time somebody wanted a GC in C++ meant their design was wrong.

Comment: @Gene: you should probably tell Hans Boehm and Bjarne Stroustrup that. Both of them are keen to get mark/sweep-style GC into C++.

Comment: I like to think of `smart pointers` as `fine grain deterministic garbage collectors`.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I think I understand their motivation and I disagree with them. There are already languages for people who want GC. In C++ I think the efforts should be directed in strengthening value semantics, not trying to cover landmines of pointer semantics.

Answer (score 2):

C++0x supports shared_ptr that uses reference counting to keep track of memory allocation. If used carefully, it serves as a good garbage collector.

The shared_ptr deallocates the memory when there are no objects left referring to a memory block (reference count has reached 0).

- This [tutorial on shared_ptr](http://www.eventhelix.com/RealtimeMantra/Object_Oriented/stl-tutorial.htm#STL_3%3a_Smart_Pointers_-_unique_ptr_and_shared_ptr) should get you started.
- Here is an [advanced tutorial on shared_ptr internals](http://www.eventhelix.com/RealtimeMantra/Object_Oriented/stl-tutorial-advanced.htm#Advanced_STL_1%3a_shared_ptr_internals)

Comment: Thanks for the links, been looking for material like that for a while :)

Answer (score 1):

Look up Boehm's garbage collector. I don't think it has multiple GC containers out of the box, but you can add this feature yourself if you absolutely need it.

Answer (score 0):

[libgc](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/libgc.html) is a good option for garbage collection library in C/C++

Comment: Your link seems to be obsolete.

Comment: latest snapshot in web archive of the now broken link: http://web.archive.org/web/20120427084748/http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/libgc.html

Comment: This is also a conservative collector like Boehm's garbage collector it seems.