# Memory Management Design

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am having some issues designing the memory management for an Entity-Component system and am having some issues coming up with the detail of the design.  Here is what I am trying to do (note that all of these classes except `Entity` are actually virtual, so will have many different specific implementations):

The `Program` class will have a container of `Entity`'s.  The `Program` will loop through the `Entity`'s and call update on each of them.  It will also have a few `SubSystem`'s, which it will also update on each loop through.

Each `Entity` will contain two types of `Component`'s.  All of them will be owned by a `unique_ptr` inside the `Entity` since their lifetime is directly tied to the entity.  One type, `UpdateableComponent`, will be updated when the `Entity.update()` method is called.  The second type `SubSystemComponent` will be updated from within their respective `SubSystem`.

Now here are my two problems.  The first is that some of the `Component`'s will control the lifetime of their parent `Entity`.  My current idea for this is that `Component` will be able to call a function `parent.die()` which would change an internal flag inside `Entity`.  Then after `Program` finishes looping through its updates, it loops through a second time and removes each `Entity` which was marked for deletion during the last update.  I don't know if this is an efficient or smart way to go about it, although it should avoid the problem of an `Entity` dieing while its `Component`'s are still updating.

The second issue is that I am not sure how to reference `SubSystemComponent`'s from within `SubSystem`.  Since they are refered to by a `unique_ptr` from inside `Entity`, I can't use a `shared_ptr` or a `weak_ptr`, and a standard pointer would end up dangling when the `Entity` owning a component dies.  I could switch to a `shared_ptr` inside the `Entity` for these, then use a `weak_ptr` in the `SubSystem`'s, however I would prefer to not do this because the whole point is that `Entity` completely owns its `Component`'s.

So 2 things:

- Can my first idea be improved upon in a meaningful way?
- Is there an easy way to implement a `weak_ptr` sort of functionality with `unique_ptr`, or should I just switch to `shared_ptr` and just make sure to not create more than one `shared_ptr` to the `SubSystemComponent`'s

Comment: I think you may want to do a little bit more research on memory management unless you are dead-set on this design; looping through your entire allocated memory space multiple times will not be scalable.  Smart pointers are always a good and simple way to start initially.  Additionally, there are already a few well-established C++ libraries that do [garbage collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81062/garbage-collection-libraries-in-c).

Comment: @Aggieboy I have already thought about the scaling issue, and have worked out loading only portions of the data into `Entity`'s limiting me to a few thousand (maybe 10-20 at most) at once.  Would the second loop really be that inefficient if I simply call a bool getter, and optionally remove `Entity`'s from the container.  This design is more to increase code reusability rather than performance, and I can easily optimize bottlenecks later.

Comment: You could simply check for the `hasToDie` flag before you try updating a component, that is not an issue. However, `unique_ptr`s are explicitly designed for singular, strict ownership. As long as more than one object needs a reference (which is guaranteed to be always valid or at least checkable), you won't get past `shared_ptr` and possibly `weak_ptr`, as you  already pointed out.

Comment: @arne the one issue I have with checking during the update loop, is that imagine the update detects collisions.  The first Entity will be able to collide with "dead" objects while the last Entity will not.  Although, if I loop through the updates first, checking for death, then do the SubSystem updates, which would include interactions like collisions. . . maybe that would simplify it.

Answer (score 1):

> Can my first idea be improved upon in a meaningful way?

Hard to say without knowing more about the nature of the work being undertaken.  For example, you haven't said anything about your use of threads, but it seems your design gives equal priority to all the possible updates by cycling through things in a set sequence.  For some things where low latency is important, or there's some useful prioritorisation that would ideally be done, a looping sequence like that isn't good, while other times it's ideal.

There are other ways to coordinate the Component-driven removal of Entities from the Program:

- return codes could bubble up to the loop over entities, triggering an erase from the container of Entities,
- an Observer pattern or lambda/`std::function` could allow the Program to specify cleanup behaviour.

> Is there an easy way to implement a weak_ptr sort of functionality with unique_ptr,

No.

> or should I just switch to shared_ptr and just make sure to not create more than one shared_ptr to the SubSystemComponent's

It sounds like a reasonable fit.  You could even wrap a `shared_ptr` in a non-copyable class to avoid accidental mistakes.

Alternatively - as for Entity destruction above - you could coordinate the linkage between `SubSystem` and `SubSystemComponent` using events, so the `SubSystemComponent` destructor calls back to the `SubSystem`.  An Observer pattern is one way to do this, a `SubSystemComponent`-side `std::function` fed a lambda is even more flexible.  Either way, the `Subsystem` removes the `SubSystemComponent` from its records.